# How to locate the source codes by PC for smart contracts

Tags: solidity, remix, compilation

Similar to the debugger module in remix `https://remix.ethereum.org/`, it can locate the source codes of each PC. Now, I want a tool that can locate the source codes given a PC for large-scale smart contracts. Is there any related tool?

Comment: Hi there. What do you mean by "PC"?

Comment: @RichardHorrocks  "PC" means "program counter"